# How to color cell in pandas dataframe for the cell value greater than average of column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, colors, highlight

I want to highlight the cell values with green for exceeding column average and those below average in Red and default in no color fill.
How to acheive this in Pandas ? Please suggest.

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIlTI.png)

Comment: Many questions about that. Try something out first, then come back when you're stuck in some point ;}